# How to set maximal retry of consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I would like to know, if it exists a property for consumer, when the kafka server is not available to set how many times that it should try to connect to the kafka server.

I've also tried:

```
.withProperty(ConsumerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MAX_MS_CONFIG, "4000")
.withProperty(ConsumerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "500")
.withProperty(ConsumerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "500")
```

and it seems, it does not work. With the settings above, I am expecting, that the consumer would stop after 4s reconnection.

As far as I know, for producer it exists the retries property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration to restrict the number of retries from the consumer side.

However, there are parameters to control the frequency of reconnection

```
reconnect.backoff.max.ms

reconnect.backoff.ms

retry.backoff.ms
```

Comment: I've tried with `.withProperty(ConsumerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MAX_MS_CONFIG, "4000")
        .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "500")
        .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "500")` it does not stop after 4s, when the retry has failed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it will not stop ✋ , it just backs off exponentially. Your goal I assume is to avoid unnecessary network trip, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For example, I would like to test a scenario, where Kafka is not active.

Comment: If you want complete stop and retry you may have to write your own, but have you checked whether it is backing off

Comment: what is a `backing off`?

Comment: Each retry should happen less frequently

Comment: How would you write it? Check if port is available?